# Is it appropriate to use an HMAC and pepper to hash input from a limited domain

Tags: security, hash, cryptography, hmac

I have a payload `p` that comes from a limited domain. I want to hash `p` to produce a unique signature and store it. This will allow detection of duplicate `p`s that I might receive later.

Since `p` comes from a small domain, and is somewhat sensitive, I plan to use a [pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)) when hashing to prevent against rainbow table attacks (if there are better approaches to deal with limited domain data, I would welcome recommendations)

When hashing `p`, is it preferred to compute the hash via an HMAC algorithm. Per this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79577/whats-the-difference-between-hmac-sha256key-data-and-sha256key-data), `HMAC-SHA256(pepper, p)` seems like it's preferrable to `SHA256(concat(p, pepper))`.

Comment: This scenario seem analogous to password-based authentication, suggesting you ought to be using a password-based hash algorithm like argon2 or the older bcrypt. Make your iteration count as large as possible consistent with performance requirements, and use a suitably large random salt for each `p`, stored in the clear alongside the hashed value of `p`. In addition to, but not in place of, the salt you may include a single pepper for the database. The goal of the pepper is not to specifically defeat rainbow tables, but rather to defeat all attacks as long as the pepper remains a secret.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I specifically don't want to salt these hashes because I want identical values of `p` to collide

Comment: Ah, I missed that, thanks. There is a critical difference between this and the password example: in the password example you have a username to retrieve the password hash by. So ignore my salt comments.

Comment: That depends on what this is for, and what's the security model. What attacks are you seeking to mitigate? What's a "limited domain"?

Comment: @OrangeDog "limited domain" means the different types of input values are limited